# MonoMac projects cannot compile: ibtool exited with code 1 - Can't run /Developer/usr/bin/ibtool (no such file)

Tags: xcode, monodevelop, monomac

I'm moving my first steps in MonoMac.

But I stopped right at the beginning due to some configuration error. I've created a new ManoMac project in MonoDevelop, and then tried some other sample MonoMac xamarin projects from GitHub, but I always get this error compiling:

> Error: Can't run /Developer/usr/bin/ibtool (no such file).
>   ibtool exited with code 1

My configuration:

Operating System:
    Mac OS X 10.7.3
MonoDevelop 2.8.6.5
Runtime:
    Mono 2.10.8 (tarball Mon Dec 19 17:43:18 EST 2011)
    GTK 2.24.5
    GTK# (2.12.0.0)
Mono for Android not installed
Apple Developer Tools:
     Xcode 4.3.1 (1176)
     Build 4E1019
Monotouch: 5.2.5
MonoDevelop.MonoMac 2.6.0.0

All my Monotouch projects compile fine, and I have no problem with the last XCode (following the Xamarin guidelines I successfully upgraded XCode and moved it from the obsolete Developer folder to the Application folder, and downloaded the updated developer command line tools from apple).

I've tried reinstalling MonoDevelop, but with no success. I always get: "Error: ibtool returned error code 1."

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the MonoMac addin was never updated to work with Xcode 4.3.

A temporary workaraound is to setup symlinks in the proper places in /Developer.

I found the way in the MonoMac forum:

http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/MonoMac-and-XCode-4-3-ibtool-error-Solution-td4403822.html

I report it here:

When using MonoMac and Xcode 4.3, the current MD beta build fails with an ibtool error.

The solutions is to type the following commands in the Terminal console:

sudo rm  /usr/bin/ibtool

and then:

sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool /usr/bin/ibtool

Now it compiles fine.

Answer (score 5):

This problem is caused by the Xcode 4.3 installer not updating the Xcode symlinks correctly to point to the active Xcode version. You can fix it with the following command:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

This upcoming MonoDevelop 2.8.8 release contains a fix for this. You can get it from the beta update channel.

Comment: Unfortunately even the xcode-select command was missing from my system. System cannot find it. This was fixed with the symlinks as indicated below for now.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error running Xamarin on Xcode 6.2 and I solved the problem by re-installing the same version of Xcode again replacing the old version per the suggestion on this post:  [xcode-select active developer directory error on OSX Mavericks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980759/xcode-select-active-developer-directory-error-on-osx-mavericks).

I may have caused this problem as I was renaming XCode Application. I have several versions installed and was trying to keep them all straight.