# xcode-select active developer directory error

Tags: xcode, macos, npm, npm-install, command-line-tool

Saw the following error when running an `npm install` which required `node-gyp`... but could be triggered by anything which requires `xcode-select`.

> xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active
>   developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command
>   line tools instance

What is the problem?

Comment: a blunt force alternative would be just to uninstall it and reinstall it again. out of all these answers that is the only thing that worked for me

Comment: @qodeninja reinstall did not work for me

Comment: Ensure Xcode app is in the /Applications directory and it worked for me

Answer (score 1943, accepted):

This problem happens when `xcode-select` developer directory was pointing to `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` when a full regular Xcode was required (happens when CommandLineTools are installed after Xcode)

Solution:

1. Install Xcode (get it from  https://appstore.com/mac/apple/xcode) if you don't have it yet.
2. Accept the Terms and Conditions.
3. Ensure Xcode app is in the `/Applications` directory (NOT `/Users/{user}/Applications`).
4. Point `xcode-select` to the Xcode app Developer directory using the following command:
   `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

**Note**: Make sure your Xcode app path is correct.

- Xcode: `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`
- Xcode-beta: `/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer`

Comment: @qodeninja Then replace `/Applications/Xcode5-DP4.app` with the proper path, I would assume.

Comment: @MaxNanasy i mean that's obvious. But no that didnt work. I had to uninstall and reinstall xcode for it to work again

Comment: I've been bitten by this a couple of times, generally when using cocos2dx. It happens if you have alternate versions of XCode, or have some other nonstandard installation. Basically the path to pass to xcode-select should be one that contains your XCode binaries at a subpath <path>/usr/bin. If that exists, <path> is your argument to xcode-select.

Comment: Works for YOSEMITE too

Comment: How to install xcodebuild without full Xcode (which takes 2.49 GB...): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417137/xcodebuild-command-tool-without-installing-xcode-itself

Comment: For the Xcode 7 beta that runs on OS X 10.10, use `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer`.

Comment: Thanks man. It works. But when we execute the sudo code we should make sure that xcode app name is matched with the exact xcode app name. if you have renamed xcode as xcode_7 then when u execute the sudo u have to give xcode_7 in the sudo, because it will search for that stuff. Hope someone will save their time:)

Comment: So, when you install a new version of Xcode (I do mine by hand and give them different names), you need to change this link. Or have a common name and a symlink?

Comment: I didn't need to do step 2. Installing Xcode was sufficient. :)

Comment: **macOS High Sierra 10.13**, I already had Xcode 9.2 installed and faced the same issue after installing **carthage**. Just did the step 4 and that's it!

Comment: Both yours and @FranklinA answers worked for me. Writing this at 17-dec-18

Comment: I already had xcode installed, but I was getting this error.  Step 4 from this answer was all that was required to fix it.

Comment: On a new Mojave `10.14.5` install, I installed Command Line Tools 10.2.1 and then Xcode 10.2.1, and got the above error. Then, I tried using this solution, and I still got the above error. `Franklin A`'s solution worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40819686/9636

Comment: it works fine on **Catalina** but I needed to add `--unsafe-perm=true` option while using `npm install`

Comment: All I needed was 
    sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/
which correctly set the directory. 
    xcode-select --print-path
then returned "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
and Xcode command line tools started working, e.g. 
    open -h NSArray.h
started opening the correct header file, rather than triggering a complaint about my DEVELOPER_DIR.

Comment: This solution fixed this same error message when trying to do `pip install salt` on OS X 10.15.4 (Catalina). Python version 3.8.2, in case it matters.

Comment: To help with SEO (since this solved my problem), this will also fix an issue with SwiftLint running when you get the following error `illegal hardware instruction  swiftlint rules`. Thanks!

Comment: This provided the missing piece of information I needed to fix my `xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory` issue (no squiggly in front of /Applications!). Thank you so much!!!

Comment: sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer working for me and fix my issue . Thanks

Comment: Download the Xcode here. Otherwise, u would have to retry a couple of times. https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode

Comment: This worked for me:
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Comment: How the hell does this happen?

Comment: `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` worked!

Answer (score 227):

I was having an issue while trying to install packages using npm.
I got the error: "sudo xcode-select -s /Applications//Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/"

To fix this

- I opened Xcode.
- Preferences
- Locations
- Selected the Command Lin Tools: Xcode 6.1.1

Now when installing packages with npm I no longer get errors.

Comment: Fixed Robo VM setup.

Comment: THIS is the good answer and should be followed first. All the others suggesting to use sudo and even entering root mode is just bad practice

Comment: Fixed Ionic Capacitor

Comment: It saves my time! This works perfectly and easily! thanks

Comment: Fixed Cordova-Angular setup

Comment: It's Xcode > Settings > Locations in Xcode 15.2

Answer (score 219):

Other solution for those who don't want to install Xcode:

1. Install Command Line Tools (if you haven't already):

   `xcode-select --install`
2. Change the active directory:

   `sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

This worked for me (git).

Comment: from all the solutions out there for mavericks, this was the only one working for me.

Comment: I prefer this solution to installing Xcode, however it looks like you can't download `xcode-select` from Apple any longer: http://cl.ly/image/2T0u2f2D471a/content

Comment: I think I already have Command Line Tools installed, however, so this will not fix anything.

Comment: So, is the only way to get a usable `xcodebuild` to install the whole of Xcode? :-(

Comment: Looking to get a better answer here, hopefully: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19605862/unable-to-use-xcodebuild-on-mavericks-with-command-line-tools-installed

Comment: optionally, using [the installer](http://nodejs.org/download/) takes seconds and just works

Comment: **This answer seems incorrect**. The whole point is that **'xcodebuild' requires Xcode**, i.e., a full install of Xcode, nor CommandLineTools. Testing it here, switching to CommandLineTools doesn't stop the error, nor would it.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct. 
As of May 2015, when using Command Line Tools for OSX 10.10 (Yosemite), the xcodebuild command no longer functions without full xcode installed.

Comment: Yosemite 10.10.4,
the second command has solved this issue (I had command tools but didn't have Xcode)

Comment: For me, `xcode-select --install` failed but then `sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` worked.

Comment: This didn't work for me. It kept saying that Xcode was already installed. Installing from AppStore finally did it (tjmehta's answer).

Comment: MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6 
    sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer

Comment: For anyone on a fresh install of mojave, I resolved this issue by installing the cli directly from https://developer.apple.com/download/more/ I dont know why apple cant find its own servers.

Comment: On a new Mojave `10.14.5` install, I installed Command Line Tools 10.2.1 and then Xcode 10.2.1, and got the above error. Then, I tried using this solution, and I still got the above error. `Franklin A`'s solution worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40819686/9636

Comment: Worked for me in 2021, osx 11.6.1. First command said xcode-select was already installed, so ran the second one. It worked and then my original problem was also resolved. Saved me 12GB.

Comment: This worked for me on xcode 14.2.

Answer (score 206):

Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools

[image: screenshot]

Select the option matching your version of Xcode.

Comment: Click on the link and look at the image.
The solution to this problem is not complicated.

Comment: I have installed 8 xcode versions thats making and issue but the above one will resolve mine issue. You are a life saver ;)

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me when I tried to have 2 version of XCode installed. Trying `xcode-select` kept saying "error: invalid developer directory"!

Comment: This was the solution I needed.  Not sure why that command Line Tools option wasn't set.  But once I set it, it resolved my problem.  Thanks.

Comment: If you're wondering what to do, just click the "Command Line Tools" dropdown and select an option from what you see.

Answer (score 86):

Simply run `sudo xcode-select -r` which should automatically reset the path.

```
 -r, --reset
              Unsets any user-specified developer directory, so that the developer directory will be found via the default search mechanism. This command must  be
              run with superuser permissions (see sudo(8)), and will affect all users on the system.
```

Comment: wonder what will happen if i uninstalled xcode and followed the steps above since i installed CLI after xcode.  Would that messup my existing IOS app projects?

Comment: This worked for me on osx 10.14.4 with xcode 11.3.1

Comment: Worked after Big Sur upgrade (11.6).

Answer (score 61):

I just ran the following command and the issue was resolved for me:

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48154263/2227743).

Comment: worked for me immediately

Comment: Thanks, worked first try.

Comment: It worked on MacOS Sonoma.

Comment: Awesome, it was so simple ❤️

Answer (score 36):

if you installed XCode already, All you have to do is to...

- Open XCode
- Go To *Xcode* → *Preferences* → *Locations*
- From the Command Line Tools Select your Xcode
  [image]

Comment: That control only shows the current one on my system, whereas the CommandLineTools/SDKs directory shows two more SDKs.

Comment: Worked for me! Xcode is too smart to find it automatically :)

Comment: Even though it looks like it's selected, you need to actually *select* it! Confusing!

Comment: @JMK This x 1000. Talk about a wild goose chase. Apple... really?

Answer (score 33):

Type this in your terminal

```
xcode-select --install
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

Comment: Super cool! After these three commands execution finished, do remember to restart your terminal to apply the new changes.

Answer (score 11):

Just in case you're using xcode beta:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-Beta.app/Contents/Developer
```

Answer (score 11):

I had to run this first

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

then

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

and then it worked.

Comment: For me the problem was fixed after running the first command. Running the second command broke things again. So just the first one (in my case). Thank you.

Comment: I second that, just running the `--reset` fixed the problem

Comment: This worked for me too . Thanks !!

Answer (score 8):

> 1. Download Xcode from App Store.
> 2. Go to Xcode preferences/Locations/CommandlineTools
>
>    > You just have to set it to the Xcode version. It automatically points to '/Application/Xcode.app'

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem in high sierra.
running the following command solved it

```
npm explore npm -g -- npm install node-gyp@latest
```

Comment: This worked for me, except I simply reinstalled with `npm -g install node-gyp@latest`

Answer (score 4):

Simple reinstall xcode-select

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
```

Answer (score 4):

Please follow the steps below :

1. The latest version of Xcode can be downloaded from https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
2. It will be downloaded in the **'Downloads'** unless specified otherwise. Please make sure to check the path where you have downloaded and extracted the Xcode
3. Now unlike other downloaded applications, on extraction, Xcode doesn't give the option to move it to Applications
4. Note the **XCODE-ACTUAL-LOCATION** or move it to the **Applications**
5. Note if you have downloaded **Xcode** or **Xcode-beta**

Based on 4 and 5, execute one of the commands (Do not execute all of them without reading above description):

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcode-select -s /[XCODE-ACTUAL-LOCATION]/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
sudo xcode-select -s /[XCODE-ACTUAL-LOCATION]/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: 2020, Xcode this works for me. Thank you. Please read carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Install Xcode from App Store. After installing run xcodebuild with root privileges i.e. `sudo xcodebuild` and accept the language. After this `npm install bcrypt` worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

Without Xcode: create file `/usr/local/bin/xcodebuild` with content to cheat XcodeSelect

```
  #!/bin/bash
  exit 0
```

`chmod +x /usr/local/bin/xcodebuild`

Comment: I must say I'm having issues with node-gyp for some reason running `xcodebuild` when I only have CLT installed. I'd rather not install Xcode just to install some native extensions nothing to do with Mac and iOS development, so I'm very up for trying this technique to basically just shut the error up. Do you know if there are any repercussions of doing this? I can only imagine that node-gyp s calling `xcodebuild` for a reason, and by doing an `exit 0` we're breaking the toolchain for a given build, but I'm not sure, as I don't know why it'd be using `xcodebuild` in the first place. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried this, it made no difference unfortunately. I really don't want to install XCode - this is just some Apple marketing BS to force you to install it.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using Xcode beta, run

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
```

instead of

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this error **without** installing the full Xcode application. You must, however, have xcode command line tools installed.

From [here](https://medium.com/@andv/fixing-tool-xcodebuild-requires-xcode-without-installing-xcode-84edcdc17833):

> 1. `$ cd /usr/bin`
> 2. `$ sudo mv xcodebuild xcodebuild.orig` (A backup just in case)
> 3. `$ vim xcodebuild`
> 4. Paste the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $1 == '-version' ]]; then
  echo "Xcode 10.2.1"
  echo "Build version 10E1001"
else
  /usr/bin/xcodebuild.bak $@
fi
```

> 5. `$ sudo chmod +x xcodebuild`

Comment: Nice answer. Also appreciate you referencing the original source. :)

Answer (score 2):

All I did which worked is run the command on the terminal:

> sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Answer (score 1):

XCode2:
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer

Pay attention to the "\" to escape the space

Answer (score 1):

I had two instance of Xcode installed xcode.app and xcode-beta.app
When I tried to create a build with netbeans it showed me the error
"supported version of xcode and command line tools not found netbeans"

I followed the following steps:

1. "xcode-select --print-path" is equal to "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
2. "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform" exists
3. "xcodebuild -version" starts with "Xcode"

after 1 I found that it is pointing me to xcode-beta.app

so here is the solution which worked like a charm:

**sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer**

Answer (score 1):

For context, today is *Jan 28, 2019*.

On my Mac, I did two things to resolve this problem:

1. Run the following command in your terminal:
   `sudo xcode-select --install`
2. Restart your Mac.

Until I restarted the computer, the problem kept occurring in my Android Studio. After reboot, it was working just fine. Also note that I did not execute any **`--switch`** commands as others are doing. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Manually installing Command LineTool worked for me.

1. I stalled xcode through App Store
2. Still could not download Homebrew
3. I installed Command Line Tool manually through link.
4. Bing Bang Boom

https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=command%20line%20tools

Answer (score 1):

For those using a newer version of Xcode (I'm using 14.3), you need to install command Line tools.
I suggest two ways.

1. Either run this command on terminal:

   `xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch xcode-select --install`
2. Or  download the installable DMG file (command line tools for Xcode 14.3) from [this link](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode) and install it.

I stumbled upon this issue when trying to install brew on macOS 13.3.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode 10.app/Contents/Developer

languoguangs-iMac:/ languoguang$ sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode 10.app/Contents/Developer
xcode-select: error: invalid argument '10.app/Contents/Developer'
Usage: xcode-select [options]

Print or change the path to the active developer directory. This directory
controls which tools are used for the Xcode command line tools (for example, 
xcodebuild) as well as the BSD development commands (such as cc and make).

Options:
  -h, --help                  print this help message and exit
  -p, --print-path            print the path of the active developer directory
  -s <path>, --switch <path>  set the path for the active developer directory
  --install                   open a dialog for installation of the command line developer tools
  -v, --version               print the xcode-select version
  -r, --reset                 reset to the default command line tools path
languoguangs-iMac:/ languoguang$ sudo xcode-select -s "/Applications/Xcode 10.app/Contents/Developer"
```

because my Xcode name in Application is "Xcode 10",

```
sudo xcode-select -s "/Applications/Xcode 10.app/Contents/Developer"
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

didn't work because my Xcode had some special name. eg) Xcode_11.2.0_beta_2_stackoverflow.app

```
cd /applications
ls
```

Then I found my Xcode name, then replace it with

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/{myXcodeName}.app/Contents/Developer
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. I originally installed Command Line Tools separately, and then all of Xcode. What worked for me was to uninstall Command Line Tools as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29859370/1241952). Then, when trying to run `xcode-select` again, I was asked to reinstall them.

*By the way, the very reason why I found this thread was because I had installed some libraries (particularly `gcc`) with `macports`, presumably using the old Command Line Tools, and then I installed the full Xcode midway into development. So anyways, for my case, I had to reinstall `macports` after removing the stand-alone Command Line Tools, reinstalling them, reinstalling `gcc`, and then my compilation worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are only two steps required, and the full XCode.app is **not** required at all:

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
xcode-select --install
```

At this point the "Installing Softwre" dialog pops up:

[image]

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solutions helped me. I was working on an  *old* project, and I had the latest version of NodeJs installed *globally* (v14.x) on my computer.

No node version above 10.1.x worked for me and when testing I received the same error as above.

#### Solution

- I installed ["n"](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) which is a nodeJs version manager like nvm
- I downgraded my nodeJs version to 9.x
- `npm install` now works.

I will now need to update my versions, or [Specify my node version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349684/how-can-i-specify-the-required-node-js-version-in-package-json) in my package.json.

Answer (score 0):

The simple fix that worked for me is drag and drop Xcode.app from the current location (In my case it was in downloads) to Applications.