# How to build flatbuffers on OSX?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, build, flatbuffers

I'm trying to build flatbuffers on OSX but I'm not sure how to proceed exactly. According to [the doc](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/docs/html/md__building.html). I should run `cmake -G "Xcode"`. I did that and got the result:

```
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 5.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 5.1.0
-- Check for working C compiler using: Xcode
-- Check for working C compiler using: Xcode -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Xcode
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Xcode -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: Temp/flatbuffers
```

However from there I'm not sure what to do. I've tried to run `make` but got the error message `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`. Any idea how to build it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you ran cmake, you generated a project for the Xcode IDE (downloadable from the Apple app store).

If you want to build using make, use this command instead:

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
```

After that,

```
make
```

should work as intended.

Answer (score 12):

Instead `make`, just run following command in the shell:

`$ cmakexbuild`

After it finish you will get `flatc` in ./Debug folder.

Answer (score 8):

On OSX it's recommended to use Homebrew to install the flatbuffer schema compiler.

```
brew install flatbuffers
```

Usage: [Using the schema compiler](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_guide_using_schema_compiler.html)

Comment: I would not recommend that. It is important the schema compiler is the same version as the library source you use with it, so best to all build from the same git repo.

Answer (score 3):

For Mac-OSX
Make sure Xcode is already installed in your machine. If not, install it by executing command `xcode-select --install`.

1. If you need latest changes download source code from [repo](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers) or to get source code for a particular version download source from [here](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/releases)
2. `cd flatbuffers` and execute `cmake -G "Xcode" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`

   If you encounter error like

   ```
   CMake Warning:
     No source or binary directory provided.  Both will be assumed to be the
   same as the current working directory, but note that this warning will
   become a fatal error in future CMake releases.


   -- The C compiler identification is unknown
   -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
   CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (project):
   No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

   CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (project):
   No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

   -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

   See also "<sourc-code-path>/flatbuffers-1.12.0/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
   See also "<sourc-code-path>/flatbuffers-1.12.0/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

   Inside the log file CMakeError.log:

   xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
   ```

   then refer this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48154263/2987755)
   success message is :

   ```
   -- Configuring done
   -- Generating done
   -- Build files have been written to: <source-code-path>/standalone/flatbuffers-1.12.0
   ```
3. `./FlatBuffers.xcodeproj` or open project in xcode
4. Build and Run project from Xcode UI
5. `cd Debug`and you can see all the binaries present.

   [image]
6. If you want `flatc` to be available globally:
   `ln -sf <path>/flatbuffers-1.12.0/Debug/flatc /usr/local/bin/flatc`

Tried and Tested on
MacOSX: Mojave, version: 10.14.3, 10.14.6
Xcode: Version: 10.2.1(10E1001), 11.1(11A1027)

Note: Make sure you use the same version in a project for compatibility.
If you are not sure which version to pick, then you can clone the repo and go to a specific commit and build.
For e.g. For version 1.11, [Commit version](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/tree/bf9eb67ab9371755c6bcece13cadc7693bcbf264) is bf9eb67a.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the below steps to compile the flatbuffer code

- Clone the Flatbuffer repo using - **git clone https://github.com/google/flatbuffers.git**
- cd flatbuffers
- cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"
- make

Answer (score -1):

**FlatBuffers for LINUX(Ubuntu 16) install and build:**

1. cd root project folder
2. yarn add flatc
3. cd node_modules of project
4. rm flatbuffers folder(if exist)
5. git clone https://github.com/google/flatbuffers.git
6. cd flatbuffers
7. cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" (install cmake if need)
8. make
9. cd root project folder
10. change path in command in package.json file from "./flatc" to "./node_modules/flatbuffers/flatc"