# Cocoapods - xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode

Tags: cocoapods

I get the folowing error when running pod spec lint

```
 -> iOS-Slide-Menu (1.4.3)
    - ERROR | [iOS] [xcodebuild]  xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation.
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In Xcode, go to preferences, then locations and make sure a "Command Line Tools" is set

Comment: worked for me too!  lots of other solutions posted out there, and none worked for me, except for this one.  nice and simple.

Answer (score 4):

This fixed it for me:

1 - Install Xcode

2 - Run `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

See this explanation on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980759/xcode-select-active-developer-directory-error/17980786#17980786).