# Error: Could not resolve SDK path for 'macosx10.8'

Tags: c++, qt

So I just installed qt around 5 minutes ago, and when I wanted to code a simple line of text in the Push Button and try to run it, I got this error:

:-1: error: Could not resolve SDK path for 'macosx10.8'

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The problem is that the online installer for Qt currently supports OSX 10.8 (Mountain Lion) by default, and I'm guessing you are on 10.9 (Mavericks) or greater.

There is a workaround:

- Navigate to where you installed Qt (default /Users/your username/Qt) using finder
- Go to the subdirectory 5.3/clang_64/mkspecs directory
- Open the file called qdevice.pri with a text editor
- Change the line
  `!host_build:QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.8`
  to:

  - `!host_build:QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.9` if you are on OS X 10.9 (Mavericks), or
  - `!host_build:QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx` if you are on OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)
- Save the file and restart Qt Creator

Comment: Thankyou very much! This did help me, didn't think it'd be that easy as I couldn't find an answer in the internet.

Comment: OSX 10.10 and they still haven't fixed this.

Comment: Thanks for the fix @docsteer, and for the bug report, @xgdgsc. I'm on OSX 10.10 using Xcode 7.0. Changing the line to `!host_build:QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx` got me building.

Comment: @JohnBerberich: please put your comment as an answer. I beg you. I kept looking everywhere for a solution and finally got what I am looking for within you comment. Thanks

Comment: @Suda.nese: I'm glad I could help. I integrated my config change into this answer.

Comment: There is no line `!host_build:QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.8`

Comment: `!host_build:QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx` === magic command, works! Thanks

Comment: i am using macosx10.13 what should i do ?

Answer (score 51):

I'm running Qt 5.7.1 on Mac OS 10.12.2.

None of the above answers involving adding `!host_build:QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.12` to a file worked for me.

What **did** work was a small reconfigure on the XCode side of things as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17980786/1232524), the key step being entering

`sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

in the command line.

What caused the problem for me was that I installed the XCode command line tools *before* installing XCode itself which apparently makes it hard for Qt to find the Mac OS SDK.

Comment: Totally saved me hours. Thanks!

Comment: @htzfun: De nada :)

Comment: After I installed Xcode, I went from the error in the question to 'qmake: command not found'

Comment: Computers are terrible, we should throw them all in the ocean. By which I mean: thank you very much, I never would have figured this out

Answer (score 4):

add

```
QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.12
```

to your .pro file. Done and Done. (for some, qdevice.pri does not contain the !host_build line, and adding it does nothing, so just set the variable directly in the .pro file).

I have confirmed that you will eventually also have to implement this https://github.com/Homebrew/formula-patches/blob/master/qt5/xcrun-xcode-8.patch: which is just a matter of changing one line in your default_pre.prf file (for your appropriate machine aka Mac/PC, etc...)

Answer (score 3):

For Qt 5.7 and macOS Sierra

Navigate to where you installed Qt (default /Users/your username/Qt) using finder

Go to the subdirectory 5.7/clang_64/mkspecs directory

Open the file called qdevice.pri with a text editor

Add line on end file

!host_build:QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.12

Answer (score 3):

I recently upgraded from OSX 10.8 to 10.12 and ran into this using Qt 5.7

The issue was resolved by a combination of:

1) FranklinA's suggestion:

Open Xcode->Preferences->Locations->command line tools..select the CLT
[xcode-select active developer directory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980759/xcode-select-active-developer-directory-error/40819686#40819686)

..and..

2) adding to the .pro file the following line: 
QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.12

Answer (score 3):

Coming to this late.

I had this error an all I needed to do was open up the actual Xcode app (which for some reason was not findable by spotlight but was in the applications folder), accept some terms, and let it do some config.

Comment: Yes, this helped me too on macOS Sierra, Qt 5.9.1 and QtCreator installed from Homebrew. No need to edit any files.

Answer (score 1):

In QT 5.7.0, Xcode 8.0 (8A218a), Mac OSX El Capitan (10.11.6), this issue happened from sudden in already configured environment. `5.7/clang_64/mkspecs/qdevice.pri` no longer contains `QMAKE_MAC_SDK` line to modify.

I suspect some XCode part got silent update and I issue appeared again. This worked:

1. open XCode and let it reconfigure again (automatic action upon start)
2. delete .pro.user file from the project
3. reopen project in QT

Comment: So how did you fix it? That line does not exist anywhere for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using QT 5.7.0, Mac OSX Sierra (10.12), XCode 8.0, I got the typical error coming from searching in:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk
```

instead of:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.12.sdk
```

Adding the line

```
!host_build:QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.12
```

to the `Qt/5.7/clang_64/mkspecs/qdevice.pri` file, worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case , I have just opened xcode again. It start installing some components. Once it finished , I open Qt again and everything start working fine.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was accept the Xcode licence by running: `sudo xcodebuild -license accept`