# Could not resolve SDK path for 'macosx10.10'

Tags: xcode, qt, osx-yosemite

I updated my Xcode last night, and found I cannot run my code now. It shows: `error: Could not resolve SDK path for 'macosx10.10'`

My Xcode is version 7.0. And I'm using Qt on OS X 10.10.5. I didn't change anything, just updated the Xcode from App store.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a solution from [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320677/error-could-not-resolve-sdk-path-for-macosx10-8`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320677/error-could-not-resolve-sdk-path-for-macosx10-8%60).

I changed it to `QMAKE_MAC_SDK = macosx10.11` and it works. But I don't know why here should be 10.11, as I'm using OS X 10.10.5. I just guess that the Xcode updated yesterday is used for new version of Mac OS called OS X el capitan.

Comment: I found that Xcode 7 doesn't come with the 10.10 sdk anymore. What I'm worrying about is if people on Yosemite are gonna be able to run an app compiled with the 10.11 sdk. If you need to re-download the 10.10 sdk, there's a resource here: https://github.com/phracker/MacOSX-SDKs. The corresponding folder has to be placed in Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/

Comment: This line was actually missing in my case. So I have just added it and then the build was successful.