# No rule to make target SDK path for 'macosx10.10'

Tags: xcode, qt

I am using mac-osx10.10, QT5.4, VTK6.2. Getting the following error when running my code:
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework', needed by`fibersurface'.  Stop.

This is because: the folder (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk) doesn’t exists in my system. I have the corresponding folder: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk.

I was trying to solve this issue as described in [Error: Could not resolve SDK path for 'macosx10.8'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320677/error-could-not-resolve-sdk-path-for-macosx10-8%60)

However, for QT5.4.2 the "qdevice.pri" doesn't contain any "!host_build:QMAKE_MAC_SDK" parameter that I'm supposed to change as "macosx10.11".

Can anyone help me where to update this parameter "QMAKE_MAC_SDK" value?

Thanks,
Amit.

I am using OS X10 Yosemite, SDK version is 10.11 and QT-5.4.2. There is no  "!host_build:QMAKE_MAC_SDK" parameter in the qdevice.pri (in the folder /usr/local/Qt-5.4.2/mkspecs/). So don't know how to change to

Comment: I think the QMAKE_MAC_SDK was removed from qdevice.pri in Qt 5.4. It only needs modification for up to 5.3, iirc (from what I recall when occasionally maintaining our build server). So the modification shouldn’t be necessary at all, not sure why you see it. Do you reuse an old build directory that was created before last XCode upgrade? If yes try with a fresh one.