# How to install Qt on MacOS X Sierra and add qmake on terminal

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I want to install Qt on my Mac and use the qmake through terminal to compile code.  I downloaded the open source Qt Creator from Qt site, but I cannot set it up. Anyone with similar problems?
System: Mac OS X Sierra,
Qt version: 5.7. 
I'm downloading the open source installer from qt.io/download-open-source . I'm installing it to Users/MyUserAccount and i want set it up so i can compile C++ code with qmake && make

Comment: The problem statement is too vague, unfortunately. Please be specific: what exactly goes wrong? Any error messages? Which ones? How exactly are you trying to install QT? What version of QT? Of macOS?

Comment: Mac OS X Sierra, Qt 5.7. I'm downloading the open source installer from https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/ . I'm installing it to Users/MyUserAccount and i want set it up so i can compile C++ code with qmake && make

Comment: please add this information to your question and _include a clear and extensive problem statement_: okay, you're trying to install it, what stops you from doing it? Are you getting any error messages? Please elaborate on that and incorporate it into the question.

Comment: No i don't have any error messages. I install it normally... I want to compile c++ code with qmake. My problem is how to work with qmake through terminal

Comment: wait, the question is 'How to _install_ QT on Mac OS X?', which implies that you _haven't managed to install it yet_... If you'd like to work with `qmake` you should consult the documentation.

Comment: If you want to run `qmake` from command line, add the directory where `qmake` is located to `PATH` environment variable. How to do it depends on the shell you are using, for bash it is done by adding `export PATH=$PATH:<path_to_qmake>` to either `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: THIS WORKED!!! THANK YOU

Answer (score 19):

Just to provide another solution using Homebrew.

As you've found QT4 isn't compatible with Mac OSX Sierra.

You can install QT5 using:

```
brew install qt5
```

But you'll find you can't access qmake from the command line. To rectify this you'll need to run:

```
brew link qt5 --force
```

Comment: I got an error after this: Project ERROR: Could not resolve SDK Path for 'macosx'

Comment: @SnigdhaBatra That sounds related to the version of OSX you're on. A fix is described here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320677/error-could-not-resolve-sdk-path-for-macosx10-8

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run `qmake` from command line, add the directory where `qmake` is located to `PATH` environment variable. How to do it depends on the shell you are using, for bash it is done by adding `export PATH=$PATH:<path_to_qmake>` to either `~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I installed Qt 5.9.1 on OS X 10.13. I added `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/dspitzer/dev/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/clang_64/bin` to my `.bashrc`, and now qmake is in my path.

Answer (score 0):

For Installing QT4:-
https://github.com/cartr/homebrew-qt4

```
brew tap cartr/qt4
brew tap-pin cartr/qt4
brew install qt@4
```

For Installing QT5:-

```
brew install qt5
```