# qmake.stash Assignment needs exactly one word on the left hand side

Tags: xcode, macos, qt

All the sudden, Qt stops working and it throws the following nonsense message.

```
/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/.qmake.stash(35): Assignment needs exactly one word on the left hand side.
/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/.qmake.stash(36): Assignment needs exactly one word on the left hand side.
/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/.qmake.stash(37): Assignment needs exactly one word on the left hand side.
Error while parsing file /Users/XXXXX/Desktop/untitled folder/untitled/untitled.pro. Giving up.
```

The entire day I couldn't solve the issue. I've reinstalled XCode 8 plus the terminal command tools and Qt 5.8 but with no luck. I've tried the solutions in this post [Error: Could not resolve SDK path for 'macosx10.8'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320677/error-could-not-resolve-sdk-path-for-macosx10-8) but none of the solutions worked. I'm not sure what the hell is wrong with the configuration and whether XCode or Qt causes the issue.

**INFO:**

macOS Sierra 10.12.4

Based on Qt 5.8.0 (Clang 7.0 (Apple), 64 bit

XCode: Version 8.3.1 (8E1000a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove the stash file and rebuild the project.