# Project ERROR: Could not resolve SDK Path for 'macosx'

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm running :

-OS 10.10.5

-QT 5.8.0

-Xcode ? (I can't find the folder on finder)

I just downloaded the offline installer of QT 5.8 for macOS and proceeded to install it, after that they told me that I have download the Xcode which they provided in the installer, after it finished installing, I run the QT for testing purposes and this message appear : Project ERROR: Could not resolve SDK Path for 'macosx'

I have been looking for some answer and so far I did this:

typing this in the terminal

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Or trying this solution:

[Error: Could not resolve SDK path for 'macosx10.8'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320677/error-could-not-resolve-sdk-path-for-macosx10-8%60)

and it didn't work for me, I assume that I don't have the Xcode because I can't find any Xcode folder on my finder, but if I don't have the Xcode, QT should not work right?

Please bear with me with the answer, I just got a macbook laptop from my brother for about 2 month, I usually used Windows 10.

Comment: If you can't find the folder in the finder, is Xcode even installed at "`/Application/Xcode.app`"?  You may need to simply install Xcode, which you can do by going to [https://developer.apple.com/xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you don't have Xcode installed Qt will prompt an error, "Project ERROR: Could not resolve SDK Path for 'macosx' ".
I did face this issue and installed Xcode 7 (because the highest version we can install in Mac Os 10.10.5 is Xcode 7.2.1). This worked for me.

Please check this link : https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/51932