# Swift 2.0 REPL - Error in auto-import

Tags: xcode, swift, read-eval-print-loop

Currently running on OS X 10.11 Beta 2 with Xcode 7 installed but right now trying to use Swift 2.0 REPL and I'm currently bumping into the following issue:

```
Welcome to Apple Swift version 2.0 (700.0.42.1 700.0.53). Type :help for assistance.
  1> "100".toInt()
Error in auto-import:
failed to get module 'Swift' from AST context
  1>
```

Is there a certain setting or package I need to play around with to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the error was due to either an issue with the command line tools being installed after Xcode or me removing Xcode 6 as El Capitan Beta 2 only supports Xcode 7 Beta for now.

For now making sure xcode-select points to the right location was the solution I needed.

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
```

Mind you all that I only found this error after trying to build with the [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com) as well.

Kudos to [tjmehta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/645251/tjmehta) for his answer to a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17980786/4173482).

Comment: Xcode 7. Seems to have to do something with MagicalRecord 2, and some headers that were badly included, wham using cocoa pods. I started using version 3, and the problem disappeared. No idea why...