# Having trouble installing the Quartz python module

Tags: python, xcode, macos

I'm trying to get the PyUserInput module up and working on my Mac, but unfortunately I can't seem to be able to get Quartz, one of its dependencies, working.

I `cd`'d my way to the file I got from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyobjc-framework-Quartz and ran:

```
python setup.py install
```

And then it vomits back an error that looks like this:

```
Bens-MBP:pyobjc-framework-Quartz-3.0.4 benlonc$ python setup.py install
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 81, in <module>
    [ 'Modules/_coregraphics.m' ], extra_link_args=["-framework", "ApplicationServices"]),
  File "/Users/benlonc/Desktop/pyobjc-framework-Quartz-3.0.4/pyobjc_setup.py", line 460, in setup
    **k
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 112, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 268, in __init__
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 836, in resolve
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1081, in best_match
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1093, in obtain
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 629, in easy_install
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 659, in install_item
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 842, in install_eggs
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1070, in build_and_install
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1056, in run_setup
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 240, in run_setup
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 193, in setup_context
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 164, in save_modules
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 138, in resume
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1382, in loads
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1133, in load_reduce
    value = func(*args)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Can anyone give some insight? I'd really like to start looking at automated bots and other stuff but first I need this to install so I can get PyUserInput going.

Comment: possible duplicate of [xcode-select active developer directory error on OSX Mavericks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980759/xcode-select-active-developer-directory-error-on-osx-mavericks)