# Attempt to install Qt on OS X gives 'You need to install Xcode 5.0.0', but this version is so old it's not available

Tags: xcode, macos, qt, osx-yosemite

I am a Windows/Linux developer who occasionally builds for OS X - particularly in Qt.

I have a simple Qt project that I have been developing on Windows.  I now wish to build it on OS X.

I am running Yosemite.  I have installed Xcode 7 and am attempting to install Qt 5.5.

When I run the Qt installer, immediately after the prompt to log in to Qt (which is successful), I receive the following error:

> You need to install Xcode version 5.0.0.

[image: Qt installation fails]

I have attempted to locate Xcode 5.0.0 on the Apple Developer site, but this is 2 major versions behind the most recent version, and I cannot even find an installer for it.

More to the point, I do wonder why the most recent version of Qt requires a version of Xcode that is considered so old by Apple that it's not even available.

How do I overcome this problem so that I can get Qt installed on OS X?

Comment: I doubt it will solve your problem, but XCode 5.0.0 appears to be available here under "XCode 5": https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - Not sure how I missed that download.  In any case - it did solve the issue.  I guess the Qt OS X installer isn't exactly vetted.  Thanks!

Comment: Could you please also set the question as as solved

Comment: @Marco I am leaving this question open because - although I have installed Qt on OS X - I think an answer that incorporates an explanation or context regarding why the old Xcode 5 is required would be better than merely a link to it.  But, in a few days, if nobody has anything insightful to incorporate into an answer, I will answer it myself and mark it as accepted.

Comment: This is a Qt installer bug. Qt itself doesn't need the outdated xcode, and won't use it IIRC. Please report it as such, answer your own question stating that it is a Qt bug, with link to the bug report.

Comment: Looking forward to an answer to this question, as I too experienced this odd requirement.

Answer (score 79):

I ran into the same problem and solved it by following the instructions [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/740041/Installing-Qt-on-Mac-OS-X). This link describes a similar, but slightly different installer issue.

To summarize, you need to ensure that the Xcode command line tools are installed and set up correctly. I already had them installed, but had to go into `Preferences -> Locations` in Xcode and set the dropdown to the currently installed version.

The link shows an earlier version of Xcode where the path is actually `Preferences -> Downloads -> Components`.

Once I'd made this change, the installer continued successfully.

Comment: Setting the dropdown menu worked for me on High Sierra using the Qt online installer and XCode 9. Unfortunately the installer failed later on due to some other issue...

Comment: Thanks it's really helps me to install Qt (just launch xcode).

Comment: This answer still applies with XCode 10.1 and Qt 5.12

Comment: Worked for me, I had the worst experience doing that as it buzzed into my headphones and scared the hell out of me!

Answer (score 27):

The solution that worked for me (on OSX Sierra XCode 8.2.1) is to open XCode `Preferences` -> `Locations`.

There is a drop-down menu named `Command Line Tools`. Select the available XCode version here. Then restart the Qt Creator installation.

Comment: This worked perfectly on MacOS 10.13.3 when trying to run the maintenance tool to update from Qt 5.10.0 to Qt 5.10.1. Thanks!

Comment: thanx for the method. If QT already installed, after adding location of Command Line Tools, just remove from ~/.config/   QtProject folder :)

Comment: Works for me :) But why doesn't QT mention this as a suggested troubleshooting thing!?!? It just said "Xcode and developer command line tools don't exist" and I was like 'err, yeah they do, what you on about?'.

Answer (score 13):

taken from the link above, this resolved my issue:

```
sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I got the error `xcode-select: error: invalid developer directory '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'`.

Comment: What version of OS X are you running, and how was X Code installed? I just tried this again on 10.11.6 with X Code 8.1 and it works still.

Take a look at this, might be related to how X Code was installed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980759/xcode-select-active-developer-directory-error

If you've used Homebrew there may be a few additional steps, something like this might help: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/209624/how-to-fix-homebrew-error-invalid-active-developer-path-after-upgrade-to-os-x

Comment: This solved the problem for me with Xcode 8.2.1 on Mac OS 10.11.6 trying to install Qt 5.9.1

Answer (score 3):

It also might be related to accepting license agreements.

I faced the same issue described, despite I already had Xcode installed, Command Line Tools installed, and had already made sure XCode active developer folder was selected by making a `xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app`.

Following the instructions in @gus answer, I launched Xcode to check if the command line tools was really installed and properly selected. It asked for license agreements. Going to `Preferences -> Locations` as suggested, I found that everything was OK.

Relaunching Qt installation after exiting Xcode, it was now working. So maybe performing a `sudo xcodebuild -license accept` could also help (or launch XCode at least once like I did and accept agreements when prompted).

Note that on XCode 14.3.1, Ventura (macOS 13), described option is located in `XCode -> Settings -> Locations`

Issue faced using qt-unified-macOS-x64-4.6.0-online dmg

Comment: I was having this issue recently and `sudo xcodebuild -license accept` worked for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For me closing the prompt and smashing keys (alt F4, I know that its not windows) before the next prompt opened worked... qt is running fine now, as it doesn't need the old version.

Answer (score -2):

you can find the old version of XCode on the [the Apple offical site here](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/) and download .dmg of xcode 5 or 6.1 for example :

I do this and it's ok for me.