# Qt installation on mac OSX gives error Cannot open script file

Tags: macos, qt, qt5

When I run the Qt5 installer on Mac I get

> Cannot open script file at 
>   /var/folders/yr/459cs03n63g185cf1bp_3xvc0000gn/T/remoterepo-6sdgWK/qt.596.qtdatavis3d.android_armv7/installscript.qs:
>   No such file or directory

Why it cannot open this `installscript.qs` file?

[image: Qt5 installation on Mac OSX: cannot open script file]

I'm running macos Sierra

Comment: I know it has been late but you need to check that the Xcode command line tools are installed and set up correctly. Click on Preferences -> Locations in Xcode and set the dropdown to the currently installed version (usually it is left blank)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I want to share my solution: **just restart the installer**.

Another way to fix most Qt installer problems is to open https://download.qt.io/ and download the complete .dmg installer (from this folder https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/)

I had this problem I think because I kept the installation idle for long time trying to solve another problem: the installer couldn't find XCode even if I had it already installed, like in this question
[Attempt to install Qt on OS X gives 'You need to install XCode 5.0.0', but this version is so old it's not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554125/attempt-to-install-qt-on-os-x-gives-you-need-to-install-xcode-5-0-0-but-this)