# How to set active developer directory with ‘xcode-select’ for Qt installation?

Tags: xcode, macos, qt

I'm trying to install the latest version of `Qt` for mac (https://www.qt.io/). But when I try to install I get an error.

> You need to install Xcode http://developer.apple.com/xcode. If already
>   installed, then set active developer directory with ‘xcode-select’.

I've now installed `xcode 7.3.1`, and then ran the following in terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

But I'm still running into the same error (see screenshot).

[image]

Can anyone advise how I might troubleshoot this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xcode-select active developer directory error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980759/xcode-select-active-developer-directory-error)

Answer (score 26):

This fixed my error.

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

It came from the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/17980786/2009221

The first time I clicked OK the error reappeared. The second time it was accepted and the installation continued.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` did not work for me as xcode-select still marked the directory as invalid. I created a symlink to homebrew's internal target xcode dev tools directory via:

`sudo ln -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`

Reinstalling homebrew after creating the above symlink worked for me.

Comment: This is as of August, 2018 Kernel: Darwin Kernel Version 18.0.0: Wed Aug 22 20:13:40 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4903.201.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda an old thread. But I just saw a revival of this issue on macOS 14.1 (Sonoma) when installing QT.

This line solved my problem:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

**With one caveat**, I installed Xcode from App Store, and Xcode ended up the *root Application* folder `/Applications/Xcode.app/`. But if you run the above line in a newly opened terminal, it refers to Xcode in the *user's application* directory `/Users/<USERNAME>/Applications/Xcode/...`, which doesn't exist!

I recommend double check where `Xcode.app` is on your system before running this command and make sure it's a path that exists.

Answer (score -5):

sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Comment: this is exactly the same answer as posted earler: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40390272/578411 and that one is considerably better. Please add some substance and if you can't refrain from answering.