# error installing PyObjC osX

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, installation, pyobjc

I am new to Python and I am desperately trying to install PyObjC via spyder.
The command

```
pip install PyObjC
```

returns an error:

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   /private/var/folders/0v/cg_rdz_x4d32jm6hz7n5txgh3djxb1/T/pip-build-UBlDtP/pyobjc-core/

No solutions found in other posts worked. I have also tried to install the whole thing manually & via conda. 
It seems that Xcode is installed.
And it is the only module I have had issues with.

Any suggestions? :)

Note: I´m working with Python 2.7, on a macOS Sierra 10.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual error message which can help more is in the beginning of the traceback. In my case it is

```
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  ...
```

If you are getting the same, here are the answers on how to debug this:
[xcode-select active developer directory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980759/xcode-select-active-developer-directory-error)