# Creating a time serie with top and nodeJS

Tags: node.js, time-series, influxdb

I would like to create a time series and inject it into InfluxDb for a demo. I thought about using the top command (top -pid 1393 -stats cpu), and use the CPU value. And then use NodeJS to extract the data and inject it into an InfluxDB. However, there are a couple of but...:
1- The top command has a display section: can it be removed?
2- In Node, I would call (repeatedly) "top -pid 1393 -stats cpu -l 1" with the "-l 1" option to only get a singe sample. I feel it is a misuse of the fact that top generates data at given intervals (basically, I recreate in Node what top does automatically)

Is there a better way to do this - in the ideal world, I would launch top in node and "pipe" the output stream to a variable in an async way (to execute the insertion into InfluxDB).

Thanks for any hints you may have.
Christian

Answer (score 0):

In actual fact, there is a node module for this: see npm usage.
Note that you may have an issue when installing the usage module, generated by node-gyp rebuild (usage requires this module, which requires XCode in Mac platform - see https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp). To solve this, look here: [xcode-select active developer directory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980759/xcode-select-active-developer-directory-error))
Thanks - C

Answer (score 0):

To monitor the process' resource consuming metrics (correct me if I took your intentions wrong), you don't need your NodeJS stuff at all.

All you need is running Telegraf agent, with [this plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/procstat) configured, on the machine(s) you're targeting.

Point the output plugin to your Influx - and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

As mention in other comments, there are specific tools for that task. Anyway, if you still want to do it programmatically, I would suggest to either:

1. run `top` in non-interactive mode, as explained here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255100/get-top-output-for-non-interactive-shell
2. read directly the information that you need from `/proc/<pid of your process>/<file of interest>`