# problem installing Atom term3 package on Mac

Tags: plugins, atom-editor

OS:

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14.5
BuildVersion:   18F132
```

Atom:

```
$ atom --version
Atom    : 1.38.2
Electron: 2.0.18
Chrome  : 61.0.3163.100
Node    : 8.9.3
```

apm:

```
$ apm --version
apm  2.1.7
npm  6.2.0
node 8.9.3 x64
atom 1.38.2
python 2.7.10
git 2.20.1
```

Trying to install term3 throws the following error:

```
$ apm install term3
Installing term3 to /Users/paul/.atom/packages ✗
```

This part start fine, but in the middle of the messages, i got:

```
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
```

Anybody can tell me if is a npm problem or a apm problem?

Comment: You can check apm vs npm by making sure you are using Node 8.9.3, and running `npm install` on the cloned repo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xcode-select active developer directory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980759/xcode-select-active-developer-directory-error)