# How to determine if OSX pip3 version is current?

Tags: pip, macos-high-sierra

```
pip3 -V
```

returns

```
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

- How does one determine if 19.3.1 is the latest version?

## UPDATES

Per StonksMan9000:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

returned: `pip: command not found`.

This nudged me to try:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

returned: `Requirement already up-to-date`: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (19.3.1)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the latest version, you can directly do this -

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

This will upgrade pip to the latest version. To check which version is the latest one, I recommend installing [Yolk](https://pypi.org/project/yolk3k/). It can be used to check available versions for other packages as well, and is probably a better overall solution. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888027/python-and-pip-list-all-versions-of-a-package-thats-available) question for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Should i use the `pip` or `pip3` command?  Python 2.7 is also installed on the MacBook (by default)

Comment: Using ```pip``` should suffice. Things get problematic when you've multiple environments, but I think just ```pip``` should work in this case.

Comment: Yes, multiple Python versions create new challenges.  Your suggestion was very helpful to arriving at the solution.  Now that I know that I am using the latest version of pip3, I can eliminate my version of pip3 causing a [hidapi install problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59188993/4953146)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade will return 'up-to-date' if current:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

returned:

```
`Requirement already up-to-date`: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (19.3.1)
```

In all likeliness this is the same on Ubuntu and other distros.