# "pod init" causes multiple diagnostics

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

As I have successfully done many times before, I'm trying to install Firebase in an IOS app. However, my error is far before Firebase is encountered. Steps:

1. For safety, reinstall cocoa pods - 'sudo gem install cocoapods'
2. Create a pod file in the root directory of the IOS app (the directory containing the .xcodeproj file) - 'pod init'

The directory structure is as follows

```
..../FBTest
       FBTest.xcodeproj
       /FBTest
          GoogleServices-info.plist
          etc
```

This produces the following, followed by an extensive further set of diagnostics, which seem too be about Ruby

"xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance"

We don't get as far as 'pod install'

Thank you in anticipation - Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`xcode-select` developer directory is pointing to `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` instead of regular Xcode path. Try below steps,

Install command line tools, if not done already

```
xcode-select --install
```

Set the active directory

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

For detailed understanding, refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980759/xcode-select-active-developer-directory-error)

Answer (score 0):

Your Xcode-select should be pointing to the Xcode bundle instead of the command line tools path.

Eg. `sudo xcode-select -s "/Applications/Xcode.app"`