# " npx cap add ios" fails with error "Updating iOS native dependencies with pod install - failed!"

Tags: ios, angular, xcode, ionic-framework, capacitor

I just created a brand new Ionic app, using command "ionic start myApp blank"

I added the necessary angular dependencies to get "ionic serve" working properly.

I have installed capacitor using the following commands

```
npm install @capacitor/cli @capacitor/core
npx cap init

npm install @capacitor/ios @capacitor/android
```

My Package.json looks as follows,

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.1.1",
    "@capacitor/android": "^3.2.4",
    "@capacitor/app": "1.0.3",
    "@capacitor/core": "^3.2.4",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "1.1.0",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^3.2.4",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "1.1.0",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "1.0.3",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.0.1",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^3.2.4",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

I ran the following commands, which worked

```
rm -r "./www"
rm -r "./ios"
ng build
```

After this I am trying to run the following command
`ionic capacitor add ios`
(or)
`npx cap add ios`

which is erroring out as follows

```
✔ Adding native Xcode project in ios in 29.98ms
✔ add in 30.56ms
✔ Copying web assets from www to ios/App/App/public in 864.98ms
✔ Creating capacitor.config.json in ios/App/App in 699.86μp
(node:25320) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at /Users/493055/Desktop/dev/IonicExperiment/myApp/node_modules/tslib/package.json.
Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./*".
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
✔ copy ios in 908.37ms
✔ Updating iOS plugins in 5.66ms
[info] Found 4 Capacitor plugins for ios:
       @capacitor/app@1.0.3
       @capacitor/haptics@1.1.0
       @capacitor/keyboard@1.1.0
       @capacitor/status-bar@1.0.3
✖ Updating iOS native dependencies with pod install - failed!
✖ update ios - failed!
[error] ERR_SUBPROCESS_NON_ZERO_EXIT
```

AND

```
(base) AMBIN01978:myApp 493055$ ionic capacitor add ios
> npm i -E @capacitor/ios@latest
npm notice Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/
npm notice Beginning October 4, 2021, all connections to the npm registry - including for package installation - must use TLS 1.2 or higher. You are currently using plaintext http to connect. Please visit the GitHub blog for more information: https://github.blog/2021-08-23-npm-registry-deprecating-tls-1-0-tls-1-1/


up to date in 5s

136 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
> capacitor add ios
[capacitor] ✔ Adding native Xcode project in ios in 32.31ms
[capacitor] ✔ add in 33.30ms
[capacitor] ✔ Copying web assets from www to ios/App/App/public in 696.66ms
[capacitor] ✔ Creating capacitor.config.json in ios/App/App in 446.33μp
[capacitor] (node:25522) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at /Users/493055/Desktop/dev/IonicExperiment/myApp/node_modules/tslib/package.json.

[capacitor] Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./*".
[capacitor] (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[capacitor] ✔ copy ios in 715.44ms
[capacitor] ✔ Updating iOS plugins in 4.48ms
[capacitor] [info] Found 4 Capacitor plugins for ios:
[capacitor]        @capacitor/app@1.0.3
[capacitor]        @capacitor/haptics@1.1.0
[capacitor]        @capacitor/keyboard@1.1.0
[capacitor]        @capacitor/status-bar@1.0.3
[capacitor] ✖ Updating iOS native dependencies with pod install - failed!
[capacitor] ✖ update ios - failed!
[capacitor] [error] xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
[capacitor]         
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.
        
        capacitor add ios exited with exit code 1.
        
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Have been breaking my head with this issue for a couple of days now. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xcode-select active developer directory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980759/xcode-select-active-developer-directory-error)

Comment: Thanks a lot Maggini. "sudo xcode-select --reset" fixed the issue.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

I ran the following command in the terminal

`sudo xcode-select --reset`

and got rid of the error for me

Comment: Perfect answer, worked for me after trying a lot of other stuff. thanks for sharing

Comment: Worked for me. Can you post more details about how it works or why this happened?

Comment: perfect, that helped me, too.

Comment: I've been struggling with this for hours and this fixed it!!

Comment: Worked.  No idea what it does, explanation would help.

Comment: just exellent! So,,,, by running sudo xcode-select --reset, you're resetting the path for Xcode's command-line tools back to their default path.

Answer (score 41):

If you have an M1 - the issue is likely with Cocoapods.

If the other answers here fail, try:

> sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi

then inside ios/App

> arch -x86_64 pod install

then, to see if it works:

> cd..

> cd..

> npx cap sync

Comment: You were the winner. Worked exactly like you said

Comment: Thanks! Got me out of my mess with M1!

Comment: I recently got an M2 MacBook Pro and I was getting lots of problems but this finally solved them and I can deploy on the phone now. TYSM

Answer (score 8):

after this run following command line by line

1. **cd ios**
2. **cd App**
3. **pod install**
4. **cd ..**
5. **cd ..**

and then check by ionic cap open ios  problem solved   :) :)

Answer (score 2):

**Please use the below command**:

1. Initial remove ios on this project - Visual studio code

> rm -r iOS

2. Add ios on project

> npx cap add ios
> npx cap sync

3. You have facing any issue on pod install or plugin issue (E.x) No podspec found for Capacitor when running pod update or install

> npm i @capacitor/ios

Comment: This is the actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

just open your terminal with rosetta and then npx cap sync

Answer (score 0):

I rebuilt my Mac Monstery 12.6.6 from scratch.  All fresh install - Xcode, android studio, VSCode, node, cocoapods, etc.

Although

```bash
pod install
```

executed fine

```bash
ionic cap sync iOS
```

failed with op message.

Executing the following two commands resolved my issue

```bash
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me:

delete podfile.lock
add podfile.lock to gitignore

deploy

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!