# "xcrun extractLocStrings" suddenly stopped working

Tags: xcode, xcrun

I have 2 laptops and run the same script on both of them:

```
find ./ -name '*.swift' -print0 | xargs -0 xcrun extractLocStrings -o ./en.lproj
```

The "first" where script is not working

- macOS version: 12.3.1 (21E258)
- XCode Version 13.4.1 (13F100)

And receive error:

```
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "extractLocStrings", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

The "second" where script works as expected

- macOS version: 12.2 (21D49)
- XCode Version 13.1 (13A1030d)

Is there any way to make `extractLocStrings` work with the new XCode `xcrun`? maybe any alternative utils? or maybe it's not related to XCode version?

[Here](https://medium.com/@nibres/in-addition-you-can-check-xcode-extractlocstrings-tool-ec28c07023d2) is a breaf explanation what the script is actually doing.

Thank you so much for your attention and participation =)

Comment: Maybe try to reinstall the Xcode command line tools? Or run `genstrings` instead? (because `genstrings == xcrun extractLocStrings`)

Answer (score 0):

executing in terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

solved my problem. [details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17980786/1401067)