# Rumtime error during CocoaPod initialisation

Tags: ios, swift, ruby, cocoapods, podspec

I'm getting the below error when trying to run 'pod init' from Terminal. I have tried installing HomeBrew as well, but getting error there as well.

```
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `force_encoding': can't modify frozen String (FrozenError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:34:in `report'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:66:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:228:in `initialize_from_file': [Xcodeproj] Unknown object version (56). (RuntimeError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.21.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:113:in `open'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/init.rb:41:in `validate!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:333:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [xcode-select active developer directory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980759/xcode-select-active-developer-directory-error)

Answer (score 2):

Open your project in Xcode, and under Project Document, change the Project Format into XCode13.0 compatible.